# jQuery UI datepicker - minDate and setDate issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a strange issue with the jQuery UI datepicker. This is the questionable code:

```
$('#cal').datepicker();
d = new Date('07/05/2013');
$('#cal').datepicker('option','minDate',d);
d.setDate(10);
$('#cal').datepicker('setDate',d);
```

This should set the min date to July 5 and the selected date to July 10. However, both the min date and the selected date are being set to July 10. Why is this? [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/ekataz/1/edit)
*Note: I know I can get around this by creating two date objects, but I want to understand why this happens.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating the same object 'd'. So you're setting both dates to the same object which is set to 10.

You should instead do something like:

```
$('#cal').datepicker('option','minDate', new Date('07/05/2013'));
$('#cal').datepicker('setDate', new Date('07/10/2013'));
```